# How to control double quotes when writing R .csv files

Tags: r, csv

My situation is that I am attempting to write a data frame consisting of columns that have differing data types to a csv file in R.  The code I use to write the file is:

```
filename = file("equipment.csv")
write.csv(file = filename, x = equipment, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE )
```

This causes problems later when I try to load the csv file into a SQL database since some of the columns contain strings that contain ','.  If I set `quote = TRUE` in the above code, it creates problems for my numeric data types when I load to the data base.

My question: is there a way to control the way that R adds quotes to the columns when writing csv files?  I would like to be able to add quotes around the strings but not to the other data types.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thanks for your help.  The problem I am having is that R is quoting numeric data types as well as strings which is giving me trouble with my data load.  The solution that you suggest seems to do the trick.

Comment: Also, part of the problem might be that some of my column types class type: factor, which may have let to some of the apparent inconsistencies that you describe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Specify which columns you want quoted like this

```
write.csv(file = filename, x = equipment, quote = c(2,3), row.names = FALSE )
```

PS: if you want to automatically work out which columns to leave alone, you can do it like this:

```
non_numerics<-adply(1:ncol(equipment),1,function(x)print(is.numeric(equipment[,x])))
quote_val<-as.numeric(array(non_numerics[which(!non_numerics$V1),1]))

filename = file("equipment.csv")
write.csv(file = filename, x = equipment, quote = quote_val, row.names = FALSE )
```

Comment: I just saw your additional comments, I ended up doing something similar to this so I didn't have to check every column for exceptions.  My only complaint about write.csv() is that is was not obvious how to affect the column quotes while leaving the column names unquoted.  Column name quotes appear to be an all-or-nothing type of thing...